# Can a .NET TreeNode know that it's parent has changed?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

I have a class that extends `TreeNode` in .NET 3.5 (C#), `LocationNode`. This class is a `TreeNode` but contains some additional data points for easy extraction. The TreeView that these `LocationNode` objects are displayed in has Drag & Drop functionality implemented. Each `LocationNode` object has a `dirty` flag that indicates whether any of the data points I care about were changed by the user. Coincidentally, one of the data points that I care about is the parent node.

I could implement some functionality into the Drag & Drop code to determine if the parent node has changed easy enough, but for abstraction sake I would like the `LocationNode` objects to track their own dirty flag and set it to true when necessary.

Is there any way to know if the parent node has changed? I don't see any events that I can hook into from `LocationNode` that would alert me when it has been added or removed from a collection.

Ideas?

Comment: Typically drag and drop only gives and receives notifications from the containing object.  And as you said no event to bind to for the child.  (Though if you drag a child to a new parent...they would be looking at the wrong place .... yes?)  Have you looked at event aggregation?  The event arg could be ParentNode, ChildNode with the parent notifying a change and the child then looks to see if the childnode is itself?

Comment: No, you cannot tinker with the TreeNodeCollection class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add the node to the treeview, store its parent (or parent.fullpath), then when you do your dirty calculation compare the current parent to the stored.  Then in your SetClean() function, store the current parent again.

Comment: After giving it some thought, I think this is the best way to do it. It would be nice if the NodeCollection class wasn't sealed so that it could be extended to fire events on node adds and removes, but since it is this is, IMO, the cleanest way of doing it.